# In JavaScript, when do/don't Dates get converted?

Tags: javascript, date

I'm confused because typing the same date in a different format results in two different date outputs, the first converted and the second, not. Here is the code:

```
var x = new Date("2015-03-25"); // outputs Tue Mar 24 2015 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
var y = new Date("03/25/2015"); // outputs Wed Mar 25 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

Comment: they're both converted (or parsed) - but the first seems to be parsed as UTC (GMT) midnight and the second as local midnight - browsers and dates in javascript are a minefield of incompatibility

Comment: Look here:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `browsers and dates in javascript are a minefield of incompatibility` it's true for _any_ language I've used. Dates are easily my least favourite thing in the entirety of programming. I'll even take phantom problems that only manifest if you're not debugging over dates.

Answer (score 3):

The way dates are parsed by browsers is a huge pile of unpredictable inconsistency. You should not attempt it. Here's the full rundown in case you're curious: http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html

If you want consistent parsing you should implement it yourself or us a library that does it. Momentjs is widely used: http://momentjs.com/

Comment: oh jeez, that page is literally red

Comment: Excellent advice, get used to posting it often. ;-)